# without http and https, domain is not reachable

Tags: apache-2.2, dns-zone, amazon-lightsail

I have this amazon lightsail instance with static public IP pointed to my godaddy domain, everything is working except if you don't include http or https, domain is not reachable. A godaddy support verified all entries on the domain DNS zone are correct, my domain is

- thelovinggarden.com

but if you dont add http or https, it won't work, any ideas, help.

**Server info:**

1. OS: CentOS 7
2. Web server: Apache

Comment: Check your security group.

Comment: The following command times out suggesting that you have a firewall filtering port 80 (used by http) `telnet  thelovinggarden.com 80`

Comment: Which browser? It works fine here if I put `thelovinggarden.com` in the address bar without the http/https thing; no server config is gonna break that, it happens at the browser level.

Comment: @balder yes how stupid, i added http 80 to open, can you post your comment so i can accept as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `telnet  thelovinggarden.com 80` one can see that there is no response over port 80.  The likely solution is to simply open and forward port 80